# Windows Store endless loading screen

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store

Whenever I open Windows Store, it's just stuck in an endless (my patience ended after 30 minutes) loading screen. Other apps, such as Skype, work fine. It's only Windows Store that doesn't work.

So far I've tried

- Installing all available Windows updates & restarting
- Starting Store from apps.windows.com and start menu
- Running wsreset.exe
- Running apps.diagcab (more on this below)
- [Re-registering Store](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/35231-store-re-register-windows-8-8-1-a.html)
- Running `sfc /scannow` (returns a very long CBS.log, and I'm not sure what I'm looking for there)
- Running DISM

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.

### apps.diagcab results

> [image: Windows Store Apps]

My display drivers are the latest available and I'm only running Windows Defender as antivirus.

### CBS.log

(from sfc)

https://i.3v.fi/CBS.log

### DISM log

```
[1680] Caller did not request sparse mount
[1680] Mounting new image.
Wim:         [\\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim]
Image Index: [1]
Mount Path:  [C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\b887443b-888f-4048-9cdd-02492983e700]
[1680] Wimserv process started for guid 0694d7d7-a638-4e34-bc87-f96a867c04f4.  Id is 392
[392] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
[392] Mounted image at C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\b887443b-888f-4048-9cdd-02492983e700.
[1680] [0x8007007b] FIOReadFileIntoBuffer:(1415): Tiedostonimen, hakemistonimen tai levynimen syntaksi ei kelpaa.
[1680] [0xc142011c] UnmarshallImageHandleFromDirectory:(511)
[1680] [0xc142011c] WIMGetMountedImageHandle:(2568)
[1680] [0x8007007b] FIOReadFileIntoBuffer:(1415): Tiedostonimen, hakemistonimen tai levynimen syntaksi ei kelpaa.
[1680] [0xc142011c] UnmarshallImageHandleFromDirectory:(511)
[1680] [0xc142011c] WIMGetMountedImageHandle:(2568)
[1680] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
[1680] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
[1680] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
[1680] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
[1680] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
[1680] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
[1680] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
[392] Received unmount request for image with guid 0694d7d7-a638-4e34-bc87-f96a867c04f4.
[392] Unmount for image at C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\b887443b-888f-4048-9cdd-02492983e700 complete.
-- snip large chunk of chinese letters --
[2176] [0x8007007b] FIOReadFileIntoBuffer:(1415): Tiedostonimen, hakemistonimen tai levynimen syntaksi ei kelpaa.
[2176] [0xc142011c] UnmarshallImageHandleFromDirectory:(511)
[2176] [0xc142011c] WIMGetMountedImageHandle:(2568)
-- snip large chunk of chinese letters --
```

Comment: I would use DISM to repair your corrupted windows insallation.

Comment: @Ramhound tried it now, didn't help.

Comment: Post the generated log for the action you performed.

Comment: @Ramhound posted the logs for both sfc and dism

Comment: Do you get the same issue when you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)? If the answer is yes, then try checking the disk for errors by running `chkdsk C: /r` from an elevated command prompt (in case you haven't already). According to the `CBS.log` you posted, there's a couple of `WebAdministration.mfl` files which are corrupted. They are part of the `Microsoft-Windows-IIS-ManagementScriptingTools.Resources` package, so they shouldn't have anything to do with the Windows Store app.

Comment: @3ventic What DISM command did you run exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

Comment: @and31415 same issue after clean boot and running `chkdsk C: /r`

Comment: @3ventic Run the `dism` and `sfc` commands again (in that order) and post here the logs. You might want to copy the files to the desktop and compress them in a `.zip`/`.7z` archive before uploading them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up fixing this was [renaming the cache folder](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/why-does-store-broker-wshostexe-keep-killing-my/4c878d5d-de09-4648-b844-834383f447f3) located at `C:\Users\<Your User Account>\AppData\Local\Packages\WinStore_<some characters>\LocalState`. After that the store launched fine.